# Maclaurin series representation

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I'm trying to find Maclaurin series for function $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2+x+1}$.

I've got so far
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2+x+1}=\frac{x-1}{x^3-1}=\frac{x}{x^3-1}-\frac{1}{x^3-1}=-\frac{x}{1+(-x^3)}+\frac1{1+(-x^3)}=$$
$$=-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n x^{3n+1}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n x^{3n}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n x^{3n}(-x+1)$$

Comment: It looks fine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
f(x) &= \frac{1}{1+x+x^{2}} = \frac{1-x}{1-x^{3}} = (1-x) \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^{3n} \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (x^{3n} - x^{3n+1}).
\end{align}